# matching login info to external file php

Tags: php, forms

I have html registration form with username and password inputs. Usernames and passwords are stored in `.txt` file like this:

```
username1,password1  
username2,password2
```

I need to match entered username and password with the stored ones. This is my code, but something is not working, can somebody advise?

```
<form action = "./get_form.php" method = "post" name = "form" > 
    Username:
    <input type= "text" name = "username" >
    Password:
    <input type= "text" name = "passwords" >
    Remember me:
    <input type= "checkbox" name = "remember" value = "checked" >
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value= "Submit Query" >  
</form>


<?php

$username= $_POST["username"];
$password= $_POST["password"];
$contents = file("passwords.txt");
$found = false;

foreach ($contents as $line) {
    $data = explode(',', $line);   

    if (($username === $data[0]) && ($password === $data[1])) {
        $found = true;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You have not posted any code.

Comment: Some advise: Don't use a text file to store login details. Your second (password) inputs name is `passwords`. That will go wrong since in your PHP you are searching for an input with name `password`. Change one of the two.

Comment: thanks for replies! this is not a real website just for educating purposes, thats why I am using text file. And sorry about the "passwords", it was just a typo. But anyway it is not working. And @Oli the code was posted, but here is it again:

Comment: <?php

$username= $_POST["username"];
$password= $_POST["password"];
$contents = file("passwords.txt");
$found = false;

foreach ($contents as $line) {
    $data = explode(',', $line);   

    if (($username === $data[0]) && ($password === $data[1])) {
        $found = true;
    }
}
?>